# Schwartz function test

Tags: elements, forall

An important class of functions in mathematical analysis, transform theory, and elsewhere is sometimes called **Schwartz functions**, after the French mathematician Laurent Schwartz.  Informally, they are "rapidly decreasing" functions (which helps ensure that certain integrals can be computed).

Specifically, such a function $f(x)$ obeys:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \pm \infty} |x|^m \left| \frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n} f(x) \right| \to 0$$

for any $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (positive integers).

I'd like to write a test routine, `schwartzFunctionQ[f_, x_]` or `schwartzFunctionQ[f[x]_]` that will take a function (e.g., `Exp[-#^2] &`) and variable and yields a `True` or `False`.

Here's what *doesn't* work:

```
schwartzFunctionQ[f[x]_] := 
  ForAll[{n,m} \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
  Limit[Abs[x]^n Abs[\!\(
  \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({x, m}\)]\(f[x]\)\)], 
    x -> \[Infinity]] == 0;
```

Test cases:

- `Exp[-x^2]` should give `True`
- `Sin[x]` should give `False`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Simplifying the derivatives like my mate @bmf and taking the special case $m=n$:

```
schwartzFunctionQ[func_, var_] := Module[{f = func, x = var, basicdef},
basicdef[f_, x_] := Simplify[Abs[x]^n Abs[D[f[x], {x, n}]], 
                      Assumptions -> {n ∈ PositiveIntegers}];
SameQ[ForAll[{n}, n ∈ PositiveIntegers, Limit[basicdef[f, x], x -> ∞]][[-1]], 0]]

f1[x_] := Exp[-x^2]
f2[x_] := Sin[x]

schwartzFunctionQ[f1, x]

(*True*)

schwartzFunctionQ[f2, x]

(*False*)
```

Thanks to my mate @bmf for the good observations ヽ(ヅ)ノ

Comment: (+1) awesome stuff. Just a correction: `schwartzFunctionQ[f2, x]` gives `False` as it should!

Comment: @bmf This problem is interesting. I already verified another case (` #^2*Exp[-#^2] &`), and it takes a long time to give me the output.

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the parameter is left as an arbitrary positive integer. and to think that this is a special case of the general study; in principle we can have both $m$ and $n$...

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks so much... and a grateful ($+1$).  But I'd like to wait for a solution with the full arbitrary case $m \neq n$ before an accept.

Answer (score 6):

Not as good as the answer by @E. Chan-López in the sense that it performs the check for a finite number of values for the doublet $\{m,n\}$, but perhaps it can be useful somehow - at least I hope

```
fordavid[function_, orderm_, ordern_] := 
  Module[{f = function, basicdef, schwarztest},
   basicdef[f_, x_] := 
    Simplify[Abs[x]^n Abs[D[f[x], {x, m}]], 
     Assumptions -> {{n, m} ∈ PositiveIntegers}];
   schwarztest = 
    If[LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[
       Flatten[Limit[
         Table[basicdef[f, x], {m, 1, orderm}, {n, 1, ordern}], 
         x -> Infinity]]] == True, 
     Print["This is a Schwartz function"], 
     Print["This is not a Schwartz function"]]
   ;
   Return[schwarztest]
   ;
   ];
```

The two test cases provided in the OP

```
fordavid[Exp[-#^2] &, 11, 13]
fordavid[Sin[#] &, 11, 13]
```

> [image: schwarz]

Comment: No, mate, I forgot an absolute value and what happens is that it returns a hypergeometric that doesn't seem to be simplifying. I think an approximation is better, so your answer seems more useful to me.

Comment: @E.Chan-López here's a test you can run after you include the absolute value that was missing, because I tried it earlier when trying to get any value for the parameters. Take the special case $m=n$, that is use only $n$ and not two parameters. You should get the proper answer.

Comment: Simplifying the derivatives is the trick. Thanks for pointing it out, mate! :-)

Comment: Thanks ($+1$)... but I'll await a full solution ($m \neq n$) before an accept.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thanks. Of course you should. I just hope that someone will manage to either use the two partial solutions or come up with a full one altogether.